# The old wireless problem

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I am suffering from the same old wireless problem. I tried everything I could find on the net as well as Ubuntu forums, but nothing works.

How can I fix this??

my device information from `lshw -C` network:

```
***product: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
configuration: driver=wl latency=0***
```

To me, what I was able to learn from the net, the driver is just the right one. but still it isn't working.

`iwconfig` shows:

```
**lo   no wireless extensions.
eth0 no wireless extensions.**
```

What other information do you need?

Comment: was it working earlier and what is the point it stopped working?

Comment: Care to explain, what is the "problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same old problem deserves the same old answer. The Broadcom STA proprietary driver offered by the Additional Drivers tool is *wrong* for your Broadcom 4311 device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and give us your report.

Comment: excellent! thank you very much sir. that worked...