# broadcom BCM4311 wirless problems with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, b43

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell D430 to replace an old version of Ubuntu. Now the wireless is not working. I have looked at a lot of the posts on the web and tried the suggestions to no avail. Can anyone give me a start? I tried using Synaptic and by using the help on the following links

https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868...rivers-bcm43xx

and also looking at the blacklist.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From a wired connection, try installing the package linux-firmware-nonfree.  That should be all the b43 driver needs to run on a clean system.  Uninstall all the other proprietary drivers first, they only interfere.  Provide more detail about your chip if that doesn't help.

```
lspci -vvnn

rfkill list
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395920/the-old-wireless-problem/

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up installing the KDE Wicd and that got the wireless working. Not sure why. Maybe someone on here can explain it.